# Not recognising variable recognised on previous line

Tags: java, netbeans

Im trying to access 2 values from each list inside a list using this for loop and i can get the first one but after that it doesnt recognise that the list. Does anyone have any ideas why

```
for (List<String> share : oriList)
        oldVal = share.get(2);
        oldCurr = share.get(1);
```

the error message on the oldCurr = line is cannot find symbol variable share

Thanks for any replies

Comment: Im an idiot and cant make a for loop

Comment: This is why you always, Always, ALWAYS use curly braces even if the body is just a single line.

Comment: maybe you got confused with python indent based blocks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `{}` for more than one line of code in your loop:

```
for (List<String> share : oriList)
{
    oldVal = share.get(2);
    oldCurr = share.get(1);
}
```

Comment: yep thanks i just noticed id forgot to that after i posted

Answer (score 1):

Python uses indentation. A code block (body of a function, loop etc.) starts with indentation and ends with the first unindented line. The amount of indentation is up to you, but it must be consistent throughout that block.

But, Java doesn't works that way. Here, we must use blocks. A block in Java is a group of one or more statements enclosed in braces. A block begins with an opening brace ({) and ends with a closing brace (}). Between the opening and closing braces, you can code one or more statements.

So, you should use braces around statements which are inside for loop like this:

```
for (List<String> share : oriList)
{
    oldVal = share.get(2);
    oldCurr = share.get(1);
}
```